# android mapping or navigation app that can get intermidiate points and their description by intent

Tags: android, google-maps, android-intent, maps

In my android app I want to ask some app to draw a route containing several points (>2) and write some description for each point in its marker.
As I understood google navigation can build route without intermidiate points.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
Uri.parse("google.navigation:q=lat,lon");
```

And Google Maps can build route with intermidiate points but without description.

```
    String address = "http://maps.google.com/maps?daddr=" + "my_lat" + "," + "my_lon"  + "+to:" +"point1_lat" + "," + "point1_lon" + "+to:" +"point2_lat" + "," + "point2_lon" + "+to:" +"point3_lat" + "," + "point3_lon";       
    Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(address));
    startActivity(intent);
```

Also looked at Yandex Maps and Yandex Navigator which also dont support intermidiate points. Does anybody knows app which supports intermidiate points with description calling by intent.

P.S Was using Google Maps API for android inside my app but then looked in pricing and doesn't understand anything. Don't want be pursued by google if my app will be popular)) Also please share with me if you know some free Android API which can build routes and show maps. Sorry for confusing explanation. 
Thank you in advance